# How do you fetch and parse xml in node.js?

Tags: javascript, xml, node.js

How do you fetch an xml from online with node.js and parse it into a javascript object?
I've been searching the npm register but only found how to parse the xml-string, not how to fetch it.

Comment: Look up how to download files (any files, not just XML). There isn't a library specifically for downloading XML because there's nothing special about XML files in that regard.

Comment: Ok. So I should download it, the parse it?
Because with rss and feedparser i could just parse it by inputting an url

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To fetch an online resource, you can use `http.get()`. The data can be loaded into memory, or directly sent to a XML parser since some support the feature of parsing streams.

```
var req = http.get(url, function(res) {
  // save the data
  var xml = '';
  res.on('data', function(chunk) {
    xml += chunk;
  });

  res.on('end', function() {
    // parse xml
  });

  // or you can pipe the data to a parser
  res.pipe(dest);
});

req.on('error', function(err) {
  // debug error
});
```

Comment: Thank you! It all starts to make sense now. =D

Comment: Don't forget that you need to include this line first: var http = require('http');

Answer (score 0):

This should work too.

```
const request = require("request-promise");

const web_url = "https://www.gillmanacura.com/sitemap.xml";

(async() => {
    let emptyData = [];   
        let resp = await request({
            uri: web_url,
            headers:{},
            timeout:10000,
            json: true,
            gzip: true
        });        
        console.log(resp)       
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

## Using node-fetch

Here an example using [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) retrieving xml.

Install a lower version of node-fetch to use require or else use regular ESM import.

> npm install node-fetch@^2.6.6

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const xml_to_js = require('xml-js');//npm i xml-js

var query = "https://api.dreamstime.com/api.xml?username="+usernamer+"&password="+api_key+"&type=get&request=search&srh_field="+term;
        
    fetch(query, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'text/xml',
        'User-Agent': '*'
        },
        }).then(function(response){ return response.text(); })
        .then(function(xml) {
        
        //convert to workable json
        var json_result = xml_to_js.xml2json(xml, {compact: true, spaces: 4});

        console.log(json_result);//json
        
        
        })
        .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
        
        });
```